# Solr ttl for DocumentExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory

Tags: solr

What is the unit for ttl when using the Solr  DocumentExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory, is it days or seconds? I was not able to find the documentation for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, ttl should be of type string.